# Android Nullpointer exception

Tags: android

I am trying to record video and save to an external SD card. However, everytime I am getting three errors

anyone knew of any tutorials or could help correct my code.

could any one help me as i am getting this three errors

```
    12-09 14:12:23.592: E/AndroidRuntime(4377): java.lang.NullPointerException
    12-09 14:12:23.592: E/AndroidRuntime(4377):     at com.mahesh.VideoStreamActivity.surfaceChanged(VideoStreamActivity.java:71)
    12-09 14:12:23.592: E/AndroidRuntime(4377):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:568)
    12-09 14:12:23.592: E/AndroidRuntime(4377):     at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:82)
    12-09 14:12:23.592: E/AndroidRuntime(4377):     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:171)
    12-09 14:12:23.592: E/AndroidRuntime(4377):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:590)
    12-09 14:12:23.592: E/AndroidRuntime(4377):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1590)
    12-09 14:12:23.592: E/AndroidRuntime(4377):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2382)
    12-09 14:12:23.592: E/AndroidRuntime(4377):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    12-09 14:12:23.592: E/AndroidRuntime(4377):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    12-09 14:12:23.592: E/AndroidRuntime(4377):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
    12-09 14:12:23.592: E/AndroidRuntime(4377):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-09 14:12:23.592: E/AndroidRuntime(4377):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    12-09 14:12:23.592: E/AndroidRuntime(4377):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    12-09 14:12:23.592: E/AndroidRuntime(4377):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    12-09 14:12:23.592: E/AndroidRuntime(4377):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-09 14:17:02.723: E/CAMERA_TUTORIAL(4596): /data/data/com.mahesh/cache/sdcard/videooutput: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

12-09 14:17:02.723: W/System.err(4596): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.mahesh/cache/sdcard/videooutput: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-09 14:17:02.734: W/System.err(4596):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
12-09 14:17:02.734: W/System.err(4596):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
12-09 14:17:02.734: W/System.err(4596):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
12-09 14:17:02.734: W/System.err(4596):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
12-09 14:17:02.734: W/System.err(4596):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:623)
12-09 14:17:02.734: W/System.err(4596):     at com.mahesh.VideoStreamActivity.startRecording(VideoStreamActivity.java:119)
12-09 14:17:02.734: W/System.err(4596):     at com.mahesh.VideoStreamActivity.surfaceCreated(VideoStreamActivity.java:50)
12-09 14:17:02.743: W/System.err(4596):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:562)
12-09 14:17:02.743: W/System.err(4596):     at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:82)
12-09 14:17:02.743: W/System.err(4596):     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:171)
12-09 14:17:02.743: W/System.err(4596):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:590)
12-09 14:17:02.743: W/System.err(4596):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1590)
12-09 14:17:02.743: W/System.err(4596):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2382)
12-09 14:17:02.743: W/System.err(4596):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-09 14:17:02.743: W/System.err(4596):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-09 14:17:02.743: W/System.err(4596):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-09 14:17:02.753: W/System.err(4596):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 14:17:02.753: W/System.err(4596):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-09 14:17:02.753: W/System.err(4596):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-09 14:17:02.753: W/System.err(4596):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-09 14:17:02.753: W/System.err(4596):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 14:17:02.753: W/System.err(4596): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-09 14:17:02.753: W/System.err(4596):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
12-09 14:17:02.753: W/System.err(4596):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:98)
12-09 14:17:02.763: W/System.err(4596):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
12-09 14:17:02.763: W/System.err(4596):     ... 20 more
12-09 14:17:02.773: D/AndroidRuntime(4596): Shutting down VM
12-09 14:17:02.773: W/dalvikvm(4596): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409951f8)
12-09 14:17:02.793: E/AndroidRuntime(4596): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 14:17:02.793: E/AndroidRuntime(4596): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
12-09 14:17:02.793: E/AndroidRuntime(4596):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
12-09 14:17:02.793: E/AndroidRuntime(4596):     at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1253)
12-09 14:17:02.793: E/AndroidRuntime(4596):     at com.mahesh.VideoStreamActivity.surfaceChanged(VideoStreamActivity.java:68)
12-09 14:17:02.793: E/AndroidRuntime(4596):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:568)
12-09 14:17:02.793: E/AndroidRuntime(4596):     at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:82)
12-09 14:17:02.793: E/AndroidRuntime(4596):     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:171)
12-09 14:17:02.793: E/AndroidRuntime(4596):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:590)
12-09 14:17:02.793: E/AndroidRuntime(4596):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1590)
12-09 14:17:02.793: E/AndroidRuntime(4596):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2382)
12-09 14:17:02.793: E/AndroidRuntime(4596):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-09 14:17:02.793: E/AndroidRuntime(4596):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-09 14:17:02.793: E/AndroidRuntime(4596):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-09 14:17:02.793: E/AndroidRuntime(4596):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 14:17:02.793: E/AndroidRuntime(4596):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-09 14:17:02.793: E/AndroidRuntime(4596):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-09 14:17:02.793: E/AndroidRuntime(4596):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-09 14:17:02.793: E/AndroidRuntime(4596):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

    code>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
    import android.hardware.Camera;
    import android.media.MediaRecorder;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class VideoStreamActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

        private static final String TAG = "CAMERA_TUTORIAL";

        private SurfaceView surfaceView;
        private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        private Camera camera;
        private boolean previewRunning;
        private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
        private final int maxDurationInMs = 20000;
        private final long maxFileSizeInBytes = 500000;
        private final int videoFramesPerSecond = 20;
        private File tempFile;



        String cacheFileName="/sdcard/videooutput";

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.camera_surface);
                    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
                    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
                    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
                    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
            }

            @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            camera = Camera.open();
            if (camera != null){
                Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
                camera.setParameters(params);

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera not available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            if (previewRunning){
                camera.stopPreview();
            }
            Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
            p.getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo();
            p.setPreviewSize(width, height);

            p.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);

            camera.setParameters(p);

            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                camera.startPreview();
                previewRunning = true;
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            previewRunning = false;
            camera.release();
        }



        public boolean startRecording(){
            try {
                camera.unlock();

                mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

                mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
                mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

                mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);

                mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(maxDurationInMs);


                tempFile = new File(getCacheDir(),cacheFileName);

                mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(tempFile.getPath());

                mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(videoFramesPerSecond);
                mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(surfaceView.getWidth(), surfaceView.getHeight());

                mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
                mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);

                mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());

                mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(maxFileSizeInBytes);

                            mediaRecorder.prepare();
                mediaRecorder.start();

                return true;
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void stopRecording(){
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            camera.lock();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at file path you're opening:

```
/data/data/com.mahesh/cache/sdcard/videooutput
```

It looks like you're opening file using incorrect path. Without code its hard to tell anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This is far easier to do with development tools. The first indicates that you are calling a pointer to an object that hasn't been instatiated or the pointer hasn't bee set an address.

The second is fairly obvious in that you are attemptong to open a file that doesn't exist, possibly due to an incorrect path or file name.

The third will most likely go once the other two are fixed.

Try placing breakpoints on the line specified in the error messages and check the values being passed.